# s3cmd with OpenPGP encryption key - is this a password or a passphrase?

Tags: encryption, amazon-s3, gnupg, s3cmd, openpgp

I setup a 10 char complex password for GnuPG with `s3cmd`.

> Run [s3cmd --configure](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd-howto)
>
> You will be asked for the two keys - copy and paste them from your confirmation email or from your Amazon account page. Be careful when
>   copying them! They are case sensitive and must be entered accurately
>   or you'll keep getting errors about invalid signatures or similar.
>
> You can optionally enter a GPG encryption key that will be used for encrypting your files before sending them to Amazon. Using GPG
>   encryption will protect your data against reading by Amazon staff or
>   anyone who may get access to your them while they're stored at Amazon
>   S3.

Now I am unsure if I supposed to setup a passphrase (not a password). Can Amazon easy decrypt (they have huge compute power) a 10 char complex password?

Comment: Voting for migration to Super User, as this is more about general tool usage and not about software development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Passphrase" is just the common term for "password" in the OpenPGP environment. The passphrase is used to derive a symmetric key through [OpenPGP's string-to-key function](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-3.7). GnuPG sets a reasonable default for the hash algorithm and number of iterations used, which makes brute-forcing an OpenPGP passphrase a very expensive operation. Brute-forcing of a ten characters passphrase is definitely not *easy* if it is random and cannot be derived from the usual password lists; if you consider your information especially valuable to entities that (a) might have access the encrypted information and (b) have vast computation powers, you might want to consider applying a stronger passphrase and/or tuning the string-to-key parameters to make testing a single passphrase more expensive.

Some more extensive discussion of the costs of brute-forcing passphrases in OpenPGP can be read up in ["At what point does adding more iterations to PBKDF2 provide no extra security?"](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/44361/19837).